# XlsxWriter - Possible to Mark a Sheet as xlSheetVeryHidden?

Tags: excel, xlsxwriter

Excel has a [function](https://www.exceldome.com/solutions/hide-an-excel-worksheet-and-do-not-permit-users-to-unhide/) to mark a sheet as `xlSheetVeryHidden`:

```
 Worksheets("Data").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
```

Is it possible to mark a sheet as `xlSheetVeryHidden` via XlsxWriter?

Comment: No, that isn’t currently supported.

Comment: @jmcnamara, if you'd like to post this as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that isn’t currently supported in XlsxWriter.